# Eclipse - Installing plugin with dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to install web tools platform for eclipse.

But alas I'm getting a big long list of unsatisfied dependencies.

I am now running Ganymede, but remember in an older eclipse installation there was an button marked ‘Select Required’ which would basically download and deal with the dependencies automatically. What happened to that button? Anyone know?　
Now there is just a button marked 'Install' which when pushed calculates the requirements and dependencies and then tells me the items are not valid with the current installation.
Do I now have to deal with the dependencies myself? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies are automatically managed through metadata included with features. The error you're getting indicates, that you're trying to install features that requires higher version of some core features already present in your Eclipse installation - while Eclipse is very modular and even multiple versions of same feature can coexist in one installation, this does not apply to number of core features.

My guess is you're trying to install WTP for the Galileo release into Ganymede. Or you've just used your Eclipse installation for too long and installed too many features already - this happens from time to time. Your best chance is to download the new Galileo release.

BTW.: most parts of WTP are already installed in many (all?) Ganymede distributions, the 3.4 update manager just does not clearly indicate that the feature is alredy installed